# My App is not installed in my firefox os simulator

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, mobile-os

I  wrote a simple hello world application for Firefox mobile. While adding a .webapp file, I got **Validation Result: OK**, But My App is not installed in simulator. My file contents are following.

Hello.webapp

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "description": "My elevator goes here",
  "launch_path": "/Hello.html",
  "icons": {
    "128": "FF101.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "Your name or organization",
    "url": "http://your-homepage-here.org"
  },
  "default_locale": "en"
}
```

Hello.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Hello Firefox101
    </title>
    <script>
        function sayHello()
        {
            alert("Hi Hello");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    This is my First App For FireFox OS.<br>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Click Me For Alert" onClick="sayHello()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Image file is in same folder.
Please guide me what I have missed. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your webapp file must be **manifest.webapp**.

Link : https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/quick_start (Part : App Manifests)

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest file name always be manifest.webapp. 
Though you are new please read developer guideline carefully. It is very helpful. Cause after developing app when you are going to published it on marketplace, you will get lots of error. Like in your simple app you use onclick funtion, inline script etc. but Firefox OS app don't support it.(link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/installable_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP)

So, better to read guideline.